# DNS Server is working localy but not accessible to the world

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have set up a DNS server using Webmin and BIND on CentOS 7. I had done this job before and everything went well. This time when I try to test it via running dig command in local server it's repponding as expected and working properly.

On local server:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> amraei.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5488
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;amraei.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
amraei.com.     100 IN  A   138.201.14.109

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
amraei.com.     100 IN  NS  ns2.amraei.com.
amraei.com.     100 IN  NS  amraei.com.
amraei.com.     100 IN  NS  ns1.amraei.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.amraei.com.     100 IN  A   138.201.14.109
ns2.amraei.com.     100 IN  A   138.201.14.109

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 138.201.14.109#53(138.201.14.109)
;; WHEN: سه‌شنبه ژوئن 07 19:34:11 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 137
```

My zone file includes:

```
$ttl 100
amraei.com. IN  SOA amraei.com. omid.amraei.com. (
            1465319605
            100
            100
            100
            100 )
amraei.com. 100 IN  NS  amraei.com.
amraei.com. 100 IN  A   138.201.14.109
ns1.amraei.com. 100 IN  A   138.201.14.109
ns2.amraei.com. 100 IN  A   138.201.14.109
amraei.com. 100 IN  NS  ns1.amraei.com.
amraei.com. 100 IN  NS  ns2.amraei.com.
```

If I ping ip address (138.201.14.109) is replying properly. I also used `nmap` to check if port 53 is listening and unblocked.

```
user@pc:~$ nmap -p53 138.201.14.109

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-07 21:10 IRDT
Nmap scan report for static.109.14.201.138.clients.your-server.de (138.201.14.109)
Host is up (0.073s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp filtered domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.46 seconds
```

But if I test it from other computer usind dig, I get timeout error:

```
user@pc:~$ dig amraei.com @138.201.14.109

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-11ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> amraei.com @138.201.14.109
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Am I missing something? What's wronge with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked port 53 using `telnet 138.201.14.109 53` and found out that is was blocked. I had forgotten to reload firewall after adding port 53 to listen to both TCP and UDP protocols.

Just shared my mistake for someone else who maybe do the same.

Comment: Good, remember to accept your answer. Fwiw, your nmap output (*state: filtered*) and dig output (*connection timed out*) already suggested this may be the case.  (It's also worth noting that both the test you did with nmap and with telnet tested 53/tcp, while 53/udp is what is primarily used for DNS)